# Displaying tags in different sizes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

How do i display my content in this way ?

What i have is an array of elements, i want them to be displayed like above, i tried using lists but i am not able to do?

**What i tried**

```
 <div class="row">
           <div class="col-lg-12">
               <ul class="list-unstyled">   
                    @foreach($categories as $category)
                        <li><a href="#">{{$category->name}}</a></li>             
                    @endforeach
             </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Usually this kind of thing uses some weight property on each of the categories. You can then set the right css property for each category based on its weight.

Comment: Would you provide some example to back up your answer? that would be really nice :)

Comment: categories are dynamically generated , like it might stop to exist at some point and if i were to do css property with respect to category , i dont think that would work right?

Comment: @BOTJr. — You need to have some logic to determine which things you want to be different sizes. Normally that has something to do with the number of items in that category. Figure that out first. (Then learn the basics of CSS and classes)

Comment: I meant use some css property. You probably want to use font-size. For example, say each category also has a `weight` property which is the font size you want for it. You could write something like `<li style="font-size: {{$category->weight}};"><a href="#">{{$category->name}}</a></li>`

Comment: okaay , i will do that as well and why the downvote/.'?

Answer (score 0):

as @NimrodArgov said, you should try to take this from a different perspective, and ask yourself how many levels of size are you planning to have and what's the logic to assign a "size" to each of these tags and see if you can implement the logic for it easily.

Once you got there, from a UI perspective it's just a question of creating the various classes (very likely just a class modifier that will use an increasing fraction of a base `em` from the container block (hope this makes sense to you). You can obviously make this as a simple mixin or function to ease the process of creating each one if you're using SASS/LESS.

I hope this helps you achieve what you're looking for.